# Show that among all triangles with fixed $s$ and $a$, the area is maximised when $b=c$.

Tags: calculus, geometry

Given a triangle $ABC$, let $a= \bigl| BC \bigr|$, $b= \bigl| AC \bigr|$ and $c= \bigl| AB \bigr|$ and let $s=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)$ be the semiperimeter.

(a) Show that among all triangles with fixed $s$ and $a$, the area is maximised when $b=c$.

So I'm thinking of using heron's formula. but I'm having a major trouble with the differentiation.

Is there an alternative method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to differentiate.

$$S = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} = C_1\sqrt{(s-b)(s-c)} = $$
$$ C_1\sqrt{s^2-s(b+c)+bc} = C_1\sqrt{s^2 - s(2s-a)+bc} = $$
$$C_1\sqrt{C_2+bc}$$

And since square root function is ascending, it's clear that the area is maximized when $bc$ is maximized.

Comment: Oh so we just have to do this my inspection then. well thanks man! I was wrecking my brain on the differentiation.